# How to find out non printable character in string in access database?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I just want to know whether my access database column text contains non printable characters like space, enter etc are exists. thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the `mysql` tag as irrelevant. Also, the correct tag for questions about Microsoft Access (any version) is `ms-access`, not `access`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE my_col ALIKE '%' & CHR$(0) & '%'
       OR my_col ALIKE '%' & CHR$(1) & '%'
       OR my_col ALIKE '%' & CHR$(2) & '%'
       OR my_col ALIKE '%' & CHR$(3) & '%'
       ... etc ...
       OR my_col ALIKE '%' & CHR$(31) & '%';
```

---

Explanation:

`&` is the concatenation (add) operator for 'string' data types.
`%` is the wildcard character for use with the `ALIKE` operator to match one or more characters.

For example:

```
'CAT' ALIKE '%A%'
```

...would evaluation `true` because 'CAT' contains an 'A' character.

If we were searching for printable characters 'A', 'B' and 'C' we could just type (print) them directly in the code as literal strings alongside the wildcard characters:

```
( 'CAT' ALIKE '%A%'
   OR 'CAT' ALIKE '%B%'
   OR 'CAT' ALIKE '%C%' )
```

...Actually we could use range of characters within square brackets:

```
'CAT' ALIKE '%[A-C]%'
```

In the case of non-printing characters, we need to use the CHR$() function to generate them but we can still use literal strings for the wildcard characters, which helps to make the code more readable. The concatenation operators are need to add the literal strings to the ones generated via function calls.

Comment: It works as a charm! However I don't get the syntax. Why so many &s?